# How do you compile WinCrypt.h under Visual C++?

Tags: c++, sdk

I have a bog-standard Visual Studio Express Visual C++ environment, installed on a bog-standard Windows 7 box.  I'd like to simply compile "#include "WinCrypt.h" (from the Windows SDK) without error.  Can someone post the prereq set of includes (and perhaps VS settings) to accomplish this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't you only have to `#include <Windows.h>` then `#include <Wincrypt.h>`?

Edit: yes that is the case.  I just tested it and the only requirements to `#include Wincrypt` are `Windows.h` and an entry point (main function) to your program.

Comment: Yep, that did it.  I looked at several generic examples and none of them were using that include, but then the examples that VS points you at don't seem very good generally.