# Can I include crypt.h in c++ on windows?

Tags: visual-c++, windows-7

I have a c++ project in which I am using crypt.h but the compiler does not recognize it: "Cannot open include file: 'crypt.h': No such file or directory". My operating system is Windows 7.

```
    #include <crypt.h>
```

Is there another name for it? Can I replace it somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer here: [How do you compile WinCrypt.h under Visual C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5665707/how-do-you-compile-wincrypt-h-under-visual-c) 
I first included `windows.h` and then `wincrypt.h` and that solve the problem for me. But be sure to respect this order, or else it won't work.